# How to fix "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python-2.7, list

I keep getting "`list index out of range`" error. I have been trying to Google a solution, but I can't find anything that fits my problem.

I tried to use other random things like `random.shuffle()` and `randint()`.

```
import random
svart = [18,28,38,58,68,78,88,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,37,26,15,57,66,75,84] 
vit = [11,21,31,51,61,71,81,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,32,23,14,52,63,74,85]

def schack(svart,vit):
    hit = 0
    miss = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        random.choice(svart)
        random.choice(vit)
        if svart == vit:
            i = i + 1

        elif svart[18] == vit[11]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[28] == vit[21]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[38] == vit[31]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[58] == vit[51]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[68] == vit[61]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[78] == vit[71]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[88] == vit[81]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[7,46,45,44,43,42,41] == vit[42,43,44,45,46,47,48]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[37] == vit[31,47,32]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[26] == vit[21,23,46]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[15] == vit[11,45,14]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[57] == vit[51,52,47]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[66] == vit[46,61,63]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[75] == vit[71,45,74]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[84] == vit[81,44,85]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[38,37,42] == vit[32]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[28,43,26] == vit[23]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[18,15,44] == vit[14]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[58,42,57] == vit[52]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[68,43,66] == vit[63]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[78,44,75] == vit[74]:
            hit += 1

        elif svart[84,88,45] == vit[85]:
            hit += 1


        else:
            miss += 1

    print hit
    print miss

schack(svart,vit)
```

This is a so-called chess simulator, that will take a value and compare the numbers from both lists. If the numbers "threaten each other", a point will be added. If both values are the same, it will not register the hit or miss and add an extra loop turn.

I don't know if I am comparing the values to each other incorrectly or what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the 29th element of the list "svart":
`svart[28]`

But the list has only 21 elements. So you are accessing an element out of the possible range. That is why you get an "list index out of range" error.